# Flex 3 - Full unicode support fonts and CSS

Tags: css, apache-flex, unicode, fonts

I'm developping a web application that will be used either in Europe or in Asia (specially Japan -Hiragana, Kanji and Katana-, China and Korea).

I'm using the following fonts:
 - ericssonga628.TTF
 - HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf
 - HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtEx.otf
 - HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf
 - HelveticaNeueLTStd-BdEx.otf

When I tried to display Japanese characters, I don't get anything.
I guess these fonts don't support East Asian characters... Do you know of any equivalent fonts?

Also, I was thinking of creating a CSS for each language (or pack of languages) when the user changes the display language.
For example, if the user selects "japanese", I'll use the japanese stylesheet.
However, how do I switch from a CSS to another?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong on this, but my guess is that these fonts simply do not contain the characters and symbols you need. I worked a bit on an application that had Indian and Chinese characters in them and it worked just fine.

You can load style SWFs using the [StyleManager](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/styles/StyleManager.html) class. There's some good info up on [Adobe Docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_10.html) about that.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your answer!
Either way, I'll need to create a new CSS for Japan with different fonts. However I don't know how to switch from a css to another... >_<